# Excel - Sum multiple column cells with given conditions

Tags: excel

I would like to sum 4 columns that may contain the value '#MI' or numeric values.  However, the 4 columns also must be compared and contrasted against each other where numeric values must be calculated over '#MI'

For example, Item AB1 has the following four column values: #MI, 1, 2, 0
The result for the product cell should be 3

Another example, Item CD1 has the following four column values: #MI, #MI, 0, #MI
The results for the product cell should be 0

Lastly, Item BB2 has the following four column values: #MI, #MI, #MI, #MI
The result for the product cell should be #MI

Thoughts?  Appreciate the help in advance

Comment: you should probably post the flat data so people can better understand what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

This works, I think:

```
E1:E3 =IF(AND(A1 = "#MI", B1 = "#MI", C1 = "#MI", D1 = "#MI"), "#MI", SUMIF(A1:D1,"<> '#MI'"))
```

Given:

```
  A   B   C   D   E
1 #MI #MI 3   #MI 3
2 #MI #MI #MI #MI #MI
3 4   5   6   7   22
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the below formula in the sum column.

```
A   B   C   D   Sum
#MI 1   2   0   3
#MI 0   0   0   0
#MI #MI #MI #MI #MI
```

`=IF(AND(A1="#MI",AND(B1="#MI",AND(C1="#MI",D1="#MI"))),"#MI",N(A1)+N(B1)+N(C1)+N(D1))`

Answer (score 0):

If the item "AB1" is in cell A2, and there are 4 columns thereafter, simply add this formula in cell F2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:E2,"#MI")=4,"#MI",SUM(B2:E2))
```

and copy it to rest of the rows as per below screenshot:
[image]